# Install Test Python Package in Different directory Using Pip

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a python distutils module that I use in production. I have that production module installed in a virtual environment. However, I'd like to be able to test upgrades before installing in the production environment. I'm also trying to avoid creating a second virtual environment. Therefore I tried the following:

```
# inside my virtualenv
# checkout master of my repo
git clone git+git://github.com/myrepo
cd myrepo
# create directory where my testing install will live
mkdir testinstall
# prepend my testing install to the PYTHONPATH to over-ride the
# production install of my repo
export PYTHONPATH=$PWD/testinstall/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
# install my local package with pip into the test area
pip install --prefix=$PWD/testinstall .
```

In this case I get the error from pip:

```
Requirement already satisfied from /path/to/production/myrepo
```

If I use

```
pip install --upgrade --prefix=$PWD/testinstall
```

pip proceeds to uninstall the production version from `/path/to/production/myrepo` and install my test version in the `testinstall` area.

Any idea how to force pip to install in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it this way instead

```
pip install --target=d:\somewhere\other\than\the\default package_name
```

Comment: This worked for me. It installs the package directly in the `target` directory. Just to note that it does not build the 'lib', 'bin', etc., just the module directory and the `*.dist-info` directory. To use it, in my python I used: `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/target:$PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use a new venv but if you really can't, use the `-t` (target) option.

```
pip3 install --upgrade -t my_new_directory
```